# Seg fault when accessing pointed to vector element by index -- what am doing wrong?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm created a pointer to a vector and adding a member to it but I can't call that member by index without getting a seg fault. Why is that?
When I use the back() method I can access it fine.

Example using index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> * a;
  a->push_back(2);
  cout<< (*a)[0] << endl;
}
// Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Example using back():

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> * a;
  a->push_back(2);
  cout<< (*a).back() << endl;
}
// 2
```

Does this mean that the back of my vector is not at index = 0 ?

Comment: Think about this: what vector does `a` point to?

Comment: For now, forget about pointers. Just create a vector: `std::vector<int> a; a.push_back(2); std::cout << a[0] << '\n';`.

Comment: "I'm created a pointer to a vector and adding a member to it but I can't call that member by index without getting a seg fault. Why is that? When I use the back() method I can access it fine."  [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and a dose of nasal demon magic.

Comment: I was actually just wanted to see how a pointer to a vector worked. I have no reason to use it. So I now get that I didn't allocate anything to it. But why does .back() work?

Comment: @George, thank you! that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Dereferencing an un-initialized pointer is segfault. `vector<int> * a;
  a->push_back(2);`

Comment: No. It's undefined behavior that may *manifest* in a segfault.

Comment: @Hadi: "*I was actually just wanted to see how a pointer to a vector worked*" - the exact same way a pointer to *anything else* works.

Comment: I find it absolutely amazing that the second version actually ran.

Answer (score 0):

The example using `back()` is wrong. You should `new` a vector object before using it:

```
a = new vector<int>();
```

Yes, your code compiles. Different compilers have different initial values of `a`.  On my system, `a` is `NULL`, so it will throw out a "segfault" on `a->push_back(2)`.

Try different compilers, the result will be different.

I am not sure what will happen if `a` has an uninitialized value, but it is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for your help.